Is electrical wiring causing issues with our kitchen oven?
We bought an LG convection range in 2012 to replace an old built in oven and stove top in our kitchen. We had to replace the bottom element in the oven three times over 11 years, thinking that it was just the way the stove was made. Last fall, I purchased a new GE profile electric range to replace it as the element had gone again. Well, two months ago, I noticed that it was taking a long time to heat up to 400, like close to half an hour and sometimes, it never reached 400 at all! The company we bought it from came and sure enough, the bottom element was no longer working. He replaced it and we had no issues until this morning when I went to bake something and again, it was taking forever to reach 400. I think it was at 290 after 15 minutes. The element must be gone again. So, is there something in our electrical that is affecting the oven element and causing this issue?

Do you have the model info, and do you know what size breaker the circuit is on?

Unfortunately these days, it can be the house/circuit electrics or just the ovens not being made with the same quality.  The circuit should be checked for loose connections and the right voltage and amps rating.  The oven instruction and a label on the oven will state the voltage and amps needed.  Common is 240v and 40 amps, but might be different for your oven.
